# To assign FK field of and entry in linqToSql C#, Exception: "An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new,...."

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am assigning an object to a reference that comes for foreign key field from a dbContext instance, then I submit changes and I am getting this exception

> "An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new,
>   perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not
>   supported."

```
Table schema is like the following, 
    __________________________
    |tbOrder      | tbPharma |
    |------------ |----------|
    |Id           | Id       |
    |..           | ...      |
    |..           | ...      |
    |PharmaId(FK) | ...      |
    |..           |          |
    |..           |          |

public FormOrder()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    currOrder= new TBL_DEMO();
    dbContext = DBContext.db; // dbContex is received from a static class

    // This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
    gridControlOrderPreview.DataSource =  new VerticalProgressBar.MyDBDataContext().tbOrders;

}

...
currOrder = gridViewOrderPreview.GetFocusedRow() as tbOrder;
...

...
Pharma pharma =  db.tbPharmas.Where(i => i.ID == pharmaId).FirstOrDefault();

tbOrder currOrder = new tbOrder();
currOrder.tbPharma = pharma;
...

...
if (currOrder.Id == null || currOrder.Id == 0)
    db.tbOrder.InsertOnSubmit(currOrder);
else
{
    targetOrder = db.tbOrders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == currOrder.Id) as tbOrder;

    // targetOrder's fields are syncronized with currOrder's fields.
    applyChanges(currOrder, targetOrder); 
}
db.SubmitChanges();
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have explored the problem.
It is originated from using different DBContext.

I realized that I feed the gridControl which is related to my currOrder from another DBContext, and I submitChanges() with another dbContext.

```
dbContext = DBContext.db; // dbContex is received from a static class

// This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
gridControlOrderPreview.DataSource =  new VerticalProgressBar.MyDBDataContext().tbOrders;
```

I changed the autogenerated code like following and problem is disappeared.

```
// This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
gridControlOrderPreview.DataSource =  dbContext.tbOrders;
```